# New Site Design is Live

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable design feedback.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug".

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: Sweet!  I just opened a question in a new tab and got a (very) nice suprise!  It's awesome!

Comment: Thanks to everyone, our amazing community and the community team for working with us. It's been a great 3 years and we're happy to finally be a permanent part of SE!

Comment: the meta looks like a black and white picture of the main site.. not outstanding, but better than default...

Comment: [here's](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/1022/2217) the first.

Comment: Yay! Now we get to find out if the [rumors of swag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268888/238438) are true

Comment: @gandalf3 The cake is not a lie.

Comment: Plot twist!  (now I have to actually get portal so I can understand what all this cake business is about..)

Comment: BTW, should meta have no polygon background for the footer? I'm not sure if thats by design or not.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I'm seeing a polygon footer. Wonder if that's catching or a browser issue. Which browser/system are you using?

Comment: I can confirm it is absent on the latest version of Chrome on Windows 10

Comment: @KurtisBeavers tried Shift-F5, no results

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I can second or third the no polygon image in the meta's footer.

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ http://i.stack.imgur.com/iTGV4.png

Comment: Ditto @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ for me.

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ should be fixed now.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Yes indeed, looks good.

Comment: I still can't believe how super cool the new design of the site looks like. I'm proud to be a member of Blenderstack :).